# How to pass all li from unorder list to div except clicked li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list item

```
<ul class="menu">

  <li> LIST 1 </li>
  <li> LIST 2 </li>
  <li> LIST 3 </li>

</ul>

<div class="append_li"></div>
```

So suppose when I click on `<li>LIST 1</li>` remaining li with tags should get appended in div tag but not clicked li, so how to do this using jQuery

Comment: Please show an attempt. Don't expect SO volunteers to write all your code for you. The jQuery docs are excellent and present a number of useful methods to do this.

Comment: Presumably you mean the content from the li's? - Semantically li's can only be children of a ul or ol  and therefore  cannot themselves be appended to the div.

Comment: @isherwood i have no idea about this so i want to know how to do this because i have requirement of this.

Comment: @Anonymous If you are indeed required to implement this, did it ever cross your mind that by doing this yourself you might learn something and it would benefit you greatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.clone()` for this purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').click(function(){
     //$('.append_li').html('');
     $('.append_li').html($('li').not($(this)).clone());
  });
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').click(function(){
     //$('.append_li').html('');
     $('.append_li').html($('li').not($(this)).clone());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">

<li> LIST 1 </li>
<li> LIST 2 </li>
<li> LIST 3 </li>

</ul>

<div class="append_li"></div>
```

***Note:*** If you want to ***replace*** data inside `<div>` instead of ***append***, then add below line in your code before `.clone()` line

```
$('.append_li').html('');
```

***Important:- What every-one talks about invalid HTML, You can overcome to that problem by doing below code***:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
   $('.append_li').html('');
   $('.append_li').html($("ul.menu").clone().find('li:eq('+ $(this).index() +')').remove().end());
  })
})
```

Output: http://jsfiddle.net/0mz9s8ng/

Comment: As I said in my comment - this solution (cloning the li into the div), simply leads to invalid HTML markup - an LI CANNOT be a child of a div. If anything the div should have been changed to an empty ul - or have the ul inside the div. This ,may achieve the result as asked, but is a poor solution. Sorry for the downvote, but part of our role in here is to suggest a better alternative to a new developers request. And providing invalid markup is the antithesis of that approach.

Comment: @gavgrif  i have added solution regarding INVALID HTML. check now

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$('.menu li').click(function (){
   $(this).siblings('li').clone().appendTo('.append_li')
});
```

OR Like this

```
$('.menu li').click(function (){
   $(this).siblings('li').appendTo('.append_li')
});
```